# Woocommerce Wordpress How do I get the Search term as a dynamic variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the search term within a woocommerce page to display it dynamically on the results page so the user knows what term they searched on.

ex. "Showing results for $searchTerm"

Is there a way to get the search term from the page that was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working through shortcodes by editing the functions.php file to include:

```
add_shortcode('searchterm', 'get_searchterm');

function get_searchterm() {

   return $_GET['ixwpss'];

}
```

Then I could use `[searchterm]` as a shortcode on the page. Unfortunately I had to "touch" the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`get_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/) and [`is_search()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/) functions like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'show_search_query_on_page', 1 );
function show_search_query_on_page() {
    if(is_search()) {
        echo '<h2>Showing results for: '.get_search_query().'</h2>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have to touch the php code. Any way to do this with shortcodes?

Comment: @ldeluca unfortunately not that I know of.